# Angular-JQM Page Structure

Tags: jquery-mobile, angularjs

jqm for making site what is the structure of page in angular-jqm i am little bit confuse to understand that
i used JQM in which the page structure looks like this

```
<div data-role="page" id="pageId">
     <div data-role="header">
     </div>
     <div data-role="content">
     </div>
     <div data-role="footer">
     </div>
</div>
```

so how the structure of page in angular-jqm?

Comment: What is the reason you chose to use jqm and angular together?

Comment: For testing purpose. I made my semester project in these technologies. But my conclusion is that if we use them together we lose benefits of both tech. Anyways i did that in last year so if any thing new comes up then share ur experience. Thanks

Comment: I agree with what you said. We truly lose benefits of both when struggling to use them together.

My opinion is that if you choose to work with angular because it gives you almost the whole package that you need to create an app, than use it only and try not to work with more frameworks, unless it is recommended to work with angular.
But this is only from my own experience and other may think differently.

I can also add that i read recently about new framework that suppose to fit angular (specially in mobile app) called Ionic and i might consider testing it.

Comment: Yeah that is. I also read about that ionic its based on angular and fully support with each other. Much nicer as compared to jqm

Answer (score 0):

If you need one controller for the whole app:

```
<body ng-app="JqmApp">
    <div ng-controller="JqmCtrl">
      <div data-role="page" id="pageId">
        <div data-role="header">
        </div>
        <div data-role="content">
        </div>
        <div data-role="footer">
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </body>
```

If you need one controller for each page (more likely):

```
<body ng-app="JqmApp">
      <div data-role="page" id="pageId" ng-controller="JqmCtrl">
        <div data-role="header">
        </div>
        <div data-role="content">
        </div>
        <div data-role="footer">
        </div>
      </div>

      <div data-role="page" id="pageId2" ng-controller="JqmCtrl2">
        <div data-role="header">
        </div>
        <div data-role="content">
        </div>
        <div data-role="footer">
        </div>
      </div>
  </body>
```

Also useful:

- http://jacobmumm.com/2011/08/30/angularjs-with-jquery-mobile/
- https://github.com/angular-widgets/angular-jqm
- http://angular-widgets.github.io/angular-jqm/master/docs/#/api/jqm.directive:jqmCachingView#Example

Comment: what if i need one `controller` for four pages
my sceneiro is that in my index page there is almost 16 pages (16 divs with `data-role="page"`) and i have four different `controller` for every four pages then how i define `ng-controller` tag surrounding every four pages in seprate `divs`? (like first four pages in one `div` and next four in 2nd `div` and so on..)

Comment: If the 4 pages really need to share one controller you could do that, but there are other ways to share $scope if that is all that is needed. Also, if the group of 4 pages look almost the same you could create a template or ngDirective instead of having 16 separate pages.